# Does there exist such a function $f(x)$ that $f^n(x)=\left (1-\frac {1}{\sqrt[n]{x}} \right)^n?$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $n=\underbrace{11\dots1}_{1996\text{ figures}}$. Does there exist such a function $f(x)$ that for all real $x \ne 0, x \ne 1$ holds
$$\underbrace{f \bigg ( f \Big( \dots \big( f}_{n\text{ iteratoins}}(x) \big) \Big) \bigg)=\left (1-\frac {1}{\sqrt[n]{x}} \right)^n?$$

Comment: That means $f (1 - 1/\sqrt [n]x)^n) = (1-/\sqrt [n+1])^{n+1} $.  Can you solve that.

Comment: Actually it doesn't have to mean that.  But it's still a way to find the funtion.

Comment: @fleablood Are you sure? It seems to me by reading the question that the relationship is true for $n=1996$, not necessarly $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Finding such an iterative function *would* work but I'm not sure one can.  I made a small error in calculating.

Comment: Same question on AOPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h436689p2463064.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. Define $ g : \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 , 1 \} \to \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 , 1 \} $ with $ g ( x ) = 1 - \frac 1 x $. Then you will have $ g \big( g ( x ) \big) = \frac 1 { 1 - x } $ and $ g \Big( g \big( g ( x ) \big) \Big) = x $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 , 1 \} $. Thus inductively we'll have
$$ g ^ m ( x ) = \begin {cases} x & m \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
1 - \frac 1 x & m \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
\frac 1 { 1 - x } & m \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \end {cases} $$
for every nonnegative integer $ m $, where $ g ^ m $ denotes $ m $'th iteration of $ g $.

Now, define $ f : \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 , 1 \} \to \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 , 1 \} $ with $ f ( x ) = g ( \sqrt [ n ] x ) ^ n = \left( 1 - \frac 1 { \sqrt [ n ] x } \right) ^ n $. It's easy to inductively show that $ f ^ m ( x ) = g ^ m ( \sqrt [ n ] x ) ^ n $ for every nonnegative integer $ m $. Thus we have
$$ f ^ m ( x ) = \begin {cases} x & m \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
\left( 1 - \frac 1 { \sqrt [ n ] x } \right) ^ n & m \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
\frac 1 { ( 1 - \sqrt [ n ] x ) ^ n } & m \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \end {cases} $$
and in particular, since $ n \equiv 1996 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 $, $ f ^ n ( x ) = \left( 1 - \frac 1 { \sqrt [ n ] x } \right) ^ n $.